Login Middle Ware on Node server not getting called
This middle ware is supposed to be called whenever the user on client side clicks the login button, instead nothing happens. I have tried opening the Login end point on a browser using http://localhost:3000/login but this end point is not opening up in a browser with 404 resource not found for using get to access it instead of post
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const socketIo = require('socket.io');
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');  // Import the cors package\
const axios = require('axios');
//require the fs module

const fs = require("fs");
const { error } = require('console');
const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketIo(server);

//variable to store a list of socket ids that are onlinecm
let online_users = []
//global to help us keep\
//add the ids to an array
let sockets = []
// Serve static files from the "public" directory
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
// Dummy user data for demonstration purposes
const users = [
    { mobileNo: '1234567890', password: 'password123' }
];
// Handle the root route
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    //load the page for the first player
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'main.html'));
});
//this server function generates a unique room ID
function generateRoomId(socketId1, socketId2) {
    return [socketId1, socketId2].sort().join('_');
}
app.use(cors()); 
app.use(bodyParser.json);
//the login end point
app.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
    console.log("end point called");
    const { mobileNo, password } = req.body;
    // Validate mobile number and password
    if (!mobileNo || !password) {
        return res.status(400).json({ success: false, message: 'Mobile number and password are required.' });
    }

    // Check if the user exists
    const user = users.find(u => u.mobileNo === mobileNo && u.password === password);

    if (user) {
        // Authentication successful
        return res.status(200).json({ success: true, message: 'Login successful.' });
    } else {
        // Authentication failed
        return res.status(401).json({ success: false, message: 'Invalid mobile number or password.' });
    }
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('user with ' + socket.id + ' connected');
    //add that socket id to the list of online users connected to this server
    online_users.push(socket.id);
    let text = online_users.join("\n");
    fs.writeFileSync("public\\online_users.txt", text);
    socket.on('joinRoom', (room) => {
        socket.join(room);
        console.log(`${socket.id} joined room: ${room}`);
        if (sockets.length > 2) {
            sockets = [];
        } else {
            sockets.push(socket.id);
        }
        console.log(sockets.length);
        if (sockets.length == 2) {
            console.log("block called");
            //this room has achieved a maximum of two users
            //send a message of true to let one user make a move
            //send the id of the opponent to the other player
            io.to(sockets[0]).emit('message', { sender: "server", message: "opponent:"+sockets[1] });
            io.to(sockets[1]).emit('message', { sender: "server", message:"opponent:"+sockets[0] });
            io.to(sockets[0]).emit('message', { sender: "server", message: "RED:true" });
            io.to(sockets[1]).emit('message', { sender: "server", message: "RED:false" });
        }
       
      
        //broadcast the name of the other client to both clients
        
    });

    socket.on('move', (data) => {
        const { room, message } = data;
        io.to(room).emit('move', message);
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log('user disconnected');
        //remove the client from the list of online_users and lso
        for (let i = 0; i < online_users.length; i++) {
            if (online_users[i] == socket.id) {
                online_users.splice(i, 1);
                //adjust the index after removalfrom
                i--;
            }
        }
        //update the text file
        let text = online_users.join("\n");
        fs.writeFileSync("public\\online_users.txt", text);
        
    });
    //handle direct communication between sockets connected to the server
    socket.on('directMessage', ({ fromSockId, toSockId, message }) => {
        //check for nulls before re directing the traffic
        
        //process the message 
        if (message.includes("is challenging you to a checkers game")) {
            //send the target message to the target client
            console.log("sender: " + `${fromSockId}`);
            console.log("receiver: " + toSockId);
            io.to(toSockId).emit('message', { sender: fromSockId, message });
            console.log(message);
        }
        //check if the target client has accepted challenge
        if (message.includes("accept")){
            console.log("sender: " + `${fromSockId}`);
            console.log("receiver: " + toSockId);
            io.to(toSockId).emit('message', { sender: fromSockId, message });
            console.log(message);
        }
        //check if it is a move event
        if (message.includes("move right")) {
            io.to(toSockId).emit('message', { sender: fromSockId, message });
            console.log("checker move relayed to the other user successfully");
        }
        console.log("message relayed to the other client successfully");
    }); 
    //this method is for sending a challenge to a prospective user
    socket.on('invitePlayer', ({sourcesocket, targetsocket, message }) => {
        //send a message to the client letting him or her know the name of tne player who sent the challenge
        
    });
   
});
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
server.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
//server end point for receiving form login data


Above is the entire server side code where am interacting with different client requests
This is the client side of things
loginForm.addEventListener("submit", function(event){
    event.preventDefault(); //prevent default form submission
    let num = document.getElementById("mobileNo").value.trim();
    let pass = document.getElementById("password").value.trim();
    //the number cannot be greater than 10 characters long
    if(num.length === 0){
        alert("The mobile number field cannot be empty");
        return; // do not execute further code
    }
    if(num.length < 10){
        alert("Mobile Number too short");
        return; //do not execute further code
    }
    if(num.length > 10){
        alert("mobile number too long");
        return;
    }
    //authenticate the password
    if(pass.length === 0){
        alert("the password field is required");
        return;
    }
    //get the paassword and the number and check if they exist in the database
    console.log(num);console.log(pass);
    //use ajax to submit the request to the server
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "/login", true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
            var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            if (response.success) {
                // Store user details on client side (e.g., local storage)
                localStorage.setItem('username', response.username);
                alert("Login successful!");
                // Redirect or perform any other actions needed
            } else {
                alert("Login failed: " + response.message);
            }
        }
    };
    var params = JSON.stringify({ username: num, password: pass });
    xhr.send(params);
    console.log("ajax request succesfully made");
});

What am I doing wrong?

Through browse when you hit the url you are getting error because /login route is only accessible only for method POST. Where is middleware? You have not defined any middleware for this route app.post('/login',.....

@Subha, do I need another code to handle the data from the form? How should I do thatt?

Do you see this end point called while clicking the login button? If yes then /login route is being called. If not then there must some issue with XMLHttpRequest() that needed to be checked. Your provided data is not sufficient to say what has happened. So tell me what is the actual issue is.

@Subha, the code inside the middle ware that should listen on the data submitted from the form is not getting called because am not seeing this console.log("end point called) on the terminal

Check your browser console and network tab to check what the actual issue is.Did you get any specific error?I think this part of the code loginForm.addEventListener("submit",..   is not even getting triggered on submit.

@Subha, it is and the last line outputs to the console ajax request successfully made, all the code in the client side works, should the middle ware be after the server.listen code block?

No you don't need any other code to make it working. If you see ajax request successfully made this then problem must be in AJAX call.Let me check.

@Subha, AJAX wil respond if the server sends back some json response which is not happening

Hey change this var params = JSON.stringify({ username: num, password: pass });. it should be mobileNo: num.Check and correct this.

@Subha, Thanks, doing that

@Subha, changed it to var params = JSON.stringify({mobileNo:num, password:pass });, still not working

What error you are getting now?have you seen this line end point called in the console ?

@Subha, no that line has not been printed to the server console

Please share your entire backend code where you have defined app.post('/login',....

@Subha, sure, updating the post

@Subha, Is it safe to use a socket.io emit function to login because all I need to do is to  put a function like socket.on('login',({MobileNo:,Pass=>{});}

It's not a recommended. Rather you can try with fetch().from online you can ger plenty of example how to do that. Currently I am on break. So I need some time to check your code

@Subha, sure will try fetch

try this 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' in your xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");,Your XML code should be working.Just check once and let me know

@Subha, sure and thanks

Was it solved??
